# Calculate number of days since from timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in my database table containing timestamp.

```
SELECT id, millisecs, to_timestamp(millisecs) AS date_time FROM my_table;
id      | millisecs  |       date_time
--------+------------+------------------------
 126952 | 1494161691 | 2017-05-07 13:54:51+01
 126952 | 1494161692 | 2017-05-07 13:54:52+01
 126952 | 1494161693 | 2017-05-07 13:54:53+01
 126952 | 1494161694 | 2017-05-07 13:54:54+01
 126952 | 1494161695 | 2017-05-07 13:54:55+01
```

Then I want to calculate the number of days since `'1899/12/30'` using either the `millisecs` or `date_time` columns. As my table has large number of rows, doing this with a python function in notebook kills the kernel after sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('DAY', date_time - '1899-12-31 00:00:00+01'::TIMESTAMPTZ) 
FROM date_test;
```

(typo in previous answer - had 1899-01-01 instead of 1899-12-31.)

See the dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=11423d29c4a1d30f4acb5ca058545dd4):

Just also note in the 2nd last field in the fiddle (added):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + 1494161691 * INTERVAL '1 second';
```

Result:

```
epoch_date
2017-05-07 12:54:51
```

Which is the date in the main question.

So, it would appear that your field called `millisec` is, in fact, seconds from 1970 (aka `UNIXTIME` or similar in other RDBMS). Check out this [link](https://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/3-Converting-from-Unix-Timestamp-to-PostgreSQL-Timestamp-or-Date.html). Unless you are storing milliseconds, then I would strongly **suggest** that you shouldn't call it `millisec`.

Create and populate table:

```
CREATE TABLE date_test
(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  millisecs INTEGER NOT NULL,
  date_time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO date_test 
VALUES
( 126952 , 1494161691 , '2017-05-07 13:54:51+01'),
( 126952 , 1494161692 , '2017-05-07 13:54:52+01'),
( 126952 , 1494161693 , '2017-05-07 13:54:53+01'),
( 126952 , 1494161694 , '2017-05-07 13:54:54+01'),
( 126952 , 1494161695 , '2017-05-07 13:54:55+01');
```

Then run the query above - result:

```
date_part
    42861
    42861
    42861
    42861
    42861
```

Links [here](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=postgresql%20unix%20timestamp&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIE886IE886&oq=postgresql%20unixtime&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.7994j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) helped!

Comment: Thank you so much. Great.

Comment: Hi - and welcome to the forum! Next time, could you please include the table structure(s) as DDL (`CREATE TABLE foo (...);`) and the data as DML (`INSERT INTO foo VALUES (...);`) - help us to help you! There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look? And thank **you** for the correct answer! :-)